# IE6: Height "1em minus 1px"

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, height

I need a div with a height of exactly 1em minus 1px. This can be achieved in most browsers like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <style type="text/css">

        .helper {
            /* background-color: black; */

            position: absolute;
            top: 5em;
            left: 5em;

            width: 2em;
            height: 1em;
        }
        .target {
            background-color: #89f;

            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 1px;

            width: 100%;
        }           
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="helper">
        <div class="target"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The "target" div has the desired height. The problem is, that this doesn't work in IE6, because it ignores the `bottom` attribute, when `top` is set (a well known problem).

Is there a workaround for IE6 (maybe with multiple nested divs, with borders/paddings/margins/whatever), or will JavaScript be the only solution?

Please note, that I can't use Quirks Mode.

Comment: You had me up until the IE6 and no quirks mode combo. My sympathies, and keep your chin up. Microsoft is dropping support for IE6 completely this summer. :)

Comment: @Robusto: I hope they will make it uninstall itself ;-)

Comment: @chris_I: Uninstall itself and kick itself to the curb. =)

Comment: Amazon and Google have also dropped it along with many others.
http://idroppedie6.com/

Comment: @Rob: I'm already planning a big party for the day I can drop it... until then, I desperately need a solution (even if it's just one pixel :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the `target` div have to be physically 1px smaller or just display 1px smaller?

The easiest way would be to add in an "ie6 only" stylesheet:

```
.helper {overflow:hidden;}
.target {top:auto;}
```

This will display `target` as 1em - 1px but its real height is 1em with the top 1px is hidden.

---

IE6 is flaky when it comes to absolute positioning support.

Another solution, instead of the code above, would be to add in an "ie6 only" stylesheet:

```
.target {position:static;margin:-1px 0 1px 0;}
```

---

I see you got the absolute positioned solution to work. Great!

Comment: Thanks Emily. Very interesting, and this might go into a good direction! However, I just tried it, and the div isn't just one pixel smaller but multiple pixels (I'd say 3 or 4). Any ideas?

Comment: @Emily: Okay, I found out, that this was due to another IE6 problem with the additional div I used as a ruler to measure the height [IE6 doesn't like empty divs, and so it gave it a few pixels of extra height, which of course makes a lot of sense...] This means: Your solution is correct, it works :-) It will require to add a little bit of a workaround, but I think I can manage that.

Comment: Chris - I added a static position solution if the absolute position keeps giving you trouble.

Comment: Very nice, your second solution also works! (It just needs an additional `line-height: 1em;`) Now I'm spoilt for choice :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is it required by the client? If not then just abandon IE6 and hacks for this crappy/old browser.